# Page not loading after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have hosted my portfolio(multi page react app with routing) on github pages. It lets me navigate to another page by clicking the navigation links ([my portfolio](https://saidul-islam98.github.io/Portfolio/)) but if I refresh that page its showing the following [error](https://saidul-islam98.github.io/about). I am using BrowserRouter to navigate through the nav links.
I have found this [solution](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploying-a-create-react-app-with-routing-to-github-pages-f386b6ce84c2) of using HashRouter and tried this. But still the same error. I am at a loss at this moment. Please help

Comment: Please share some code (edit your question), preferably a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What do you already have tried do to solve  your problem?

Comment: Maybe helpful => https://www.nicateliyev.com/en/post/deploy-react-web-application-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Generally when a page doesn't reflect the expected changes to me, it's because it's loading the cached version. Try doing a hard refresh with ctrl + shift + R and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurs, because your React app can load only as index.html, and all your routes doesn't have really html files for loading.

[Read this answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-285114194), from Dan Abramov

Answer (score 0):

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

or

```
<BrowserRouter  path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}>
  {/* routes */}
</BrowserRouter>
```